# How i get the original variable name for a parameter inside a function call? (Python 3.7)

Tags: python-3.7

First, i want to say there are a few questions related to this topic but the answers are not what I'm looking for, those questions are related to files or something else so it shouldn't be count as a duplicated, but if you find a duplicated question makes me know an i will change this.

---

**Description**:

I need to print the original variable name passed to a function.

This code is an example to show what i want (Take this code as a starting point if you want):

```py
def print_var_name(var):
    original_var_name = do_something_here
    print(original_var_name)


var_1 = 'foo'

print_var_name(var_1)
```

The output should be:

```
var_1
```

Thanks you guys!